# C++ Wordlist; find a whole describtion in vector/map

Tags: c++, windows, vector, dictionary

I'm making a code were you create a wordlist. It contains a 'word' and a 'describtion'. The word and describtion has their own vectors. I'm trying the same by using maps too.

The program is going well untill I try to lookup the words. The program will only take the last word from the describtion. Is there a way to make a whole sentence to a single vector?

This is the code on how I write down the describtion. The whole program code is really long so I'll mention only the important stuff:

```
cout<< "Describe your word:"; //Describtion by using vectors
cin>> desc;         //Here you enter the decribtion
getline(cin, desc); //So you can have "space" and write a whole sentence.
d.push_back(desc);  //Place the describe at the back of the list so it is at the same index as the matching word
```

And this is the code that is supposed to show the word and describtion:

```
cout<< "Enter a word to lookup:";
cin>> word;
if (find(o.begin(), o.end(), word) !=o.end())   //Lookup if word excist in vector
{
    int pos = find(o.begin(), o.end(), word) - o.begin();   //Searches which index the word is in the vector
    cout<< "Describtion for " << word << " is " << d[pos] << endl;  //d[pos] takes the description vector that is in the same index as the word vector
}
else
    cout<< "Word not found! Try something else." << endl;   //If word not found
```

It will only take the last word from the describtion. I got the same problem by using maps:

```
cout<< "Enter a word to lookup:"; 
cin>> word;
if (L.find(word) != L.end())    //Lookup if the key excist
{
    cout<< "Describtion for " << word << " is " << L[word] << endl; //Tells what the description is for the word if it excist
}
else
    cout<< "Word not found! Try something else." << endl;   //Tells you this if key is not found
```

So, how can I get the whole describtion printed out for the specific word?

edit: I noticed that it's only the first word in the describtion that's missing (I'm stupid enough to not try with more words than 2)

So, what is wrong? How can I get the frist word in the describtion appere in the output?

Comment: Do the descriptions you've tested with all have two words?

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out, it looks like it's skipping the first word only.

Comment: Add `cout << desc << endl;` between all the lines in your reading code.

Comment: Now I see, the input does not include the first word. Does it have something to do with "getline(cin, desc)"?

Comment: I'd say it has more to do with the line before that - the one that reads the first word.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract a single `std::string` from `std::cin` it will only get one word. First you are getting the first word of the description and putting it into `desc`:

```
cin >> desc;         // Here you enter the decribtion
```

Then you are getting the remaining words in the description and putting them in `desc`. Overwriting the previous contents of `desc` (the first word):

```
getline(cin, desc); // So you can have "space" and write a whole sentence.
```

So, now `desc` contains all but the first word of the description. Consider using a debugger to find this sort of thing.

Some other advice: Avoid searching the`vector` twice. Store the results of `find` in a variable:

```
auto search = find(o.begin(), o.end(), word);
if (search != o.end()) {
  int pos = std::distance(o.begin(), search);
  // Use pos ...
}
```